# Note Field Appearing and Dissappearing

Tags: contact-view

When entering a new contact, I have an option to enter a Note in the editing mode. However, if I don't use that field when I enter the contact for the first time, the next time I open that contact in the editing mode, I don't see that field - the only place I see it is in the Notes Tab in the View Mode. Is there some option to always keep this field in the both modes?
Also, is there an option to see Notes in the Summary Tab or only in the Notes Tab?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct. The reason is mostly because you can have multiple notes, so it gets its own tab.

If you only want one "note" per contact and want it to always appear, you can create a custom field, e.g. called "comments" (to distinguish from notes), and then it will appear on the summary tab and in edit mode in an accordian section.